# How can I create a Context that has a reference inside in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-context

I am trying to create a context that has a reference inside it in React Native using Typescript, however, I am getting all sorts of type errors and I do not seem able to fix it. I want it to be null by default, but I'm not being able to do it.

`const WebContext: RefObject<WebView<{}>> | null = createContext(null);`

It is raising this error: `Property 'current' is missing in type 'Context<null>' but required in type 'RefObject<WebView<{}>>'.`

What am I doing wrong? How could I initialise this to null while being able to set it's value to a reference of a WebView later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the type of `WebContext` should be `Context<RefObject<WebView<{}>> | null>` instead of `RefObject<WebView<{}>> | null`, but that will still give a type error as `createContext(null)` yields a context of type `Context<null>`. You can widen the context type by providing a generic parameter `RefObject<WebView<{}>> | null` to the `createContext` call:

```
const WebContext = createContext<RefObject<WebView<{}>> | null>(null);
// WebContext: Context<RefObject<WebView<{}>> | null>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoMIQHZYAeMANHAEqoBmA8gEYBWqSMAvnFVBCHAORroWvANwAoUcAKooVQajgB1VHQBqwVAHcAPABUAfIlbik%20AM7wldXFOJwAvHBQYs1ojC2VajZu8trNWgisegYAPnB4AK4ANtF6ABRRsQCUYgD0aYrKrqjEAFxwOcQe1PRMLFp%206tpBIXDhSXGiQA)

Comment: Thanks! This solved it, I am pretty new to Typescript and hadn't used React Context before so I got pretty lost, thanks again! I will mark this as solved.